# Dynamic List app add button not working

Tags: android, debugging

I wrote an exercise android app which consists of a text entry, an add button, and a dynamic list. Users are supposed to be able to type a string into the text entry, click on add button, and add it to the list. However, when I run this script on the emulator, nothing happens when I click on the add button. Checking the logcat doesn't help, because no logs appear when clicking on the button either. I also tried adding a breakpoint, but, again, nothing happens when I try to step over. Can someone help me on this please? I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

```
package p.listviewexerice2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button bt;
    EditText et;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("x");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),list.get(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(v==bt){
            String name = et.getText().toString();
            if(name.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Empty entry",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                list.add(name);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you delete `lv.setOnItem..` code block and try again ? 
Because you have already implements from onClickListener, so your button call the method `onClick()`

Comment: Onlick and setonitemclicklistener are actually different. The former checks if there's a string in the entry, if there is, then it adds it to the list. The latter simply repeats the content of the item when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
list.add(name);
```

Do this:

```
adapter.add(name);
```

Explanation: you create the adapter with parameter list, allright. But since then adapter manages it's own internal list. Adapter also has built-in methods "add()" and "remove()", to manage that internal list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost fine, just 1 thing is missing. You have not registered the click event for your button bt. And without registering the click event the system will not be able to execute the code for onClick(View v).
so just add the below code in your onCreate()

```
bt.setOnClickListener(this);
```